# Wear on unmounted HDD

Tags: linux, ubuntu, hard-drive

I'm trying to minimize wear on an internal HDD (not my boot drive). I only need to access (read/write) it once in a while - maybe one or two times a week. I can't physically unplug the drive, as I don't have physical access to the machine. My question is this: **Will leaving the drive unmounted most of the time help prevent wear?**

If not, are there any other software tricks I can use to reduce wear in my situation?

Comment: *"Will leaving the drive unmounted most of the time help prevent wear?"* -- No, it's still powered up, and the life of a drive is measured in POH, powered-on-hours.  There are schemes to power-off an idle drive, but then you encounter the debate between which is worse: spin-down/spin-up cycles versus leaving the drive powered up.

Comment: Ditto what sawdust said.  Note that if you're using Ubuntu Server, it doesn't spin down idle drives by default; you have to configure `hdparm` to do it for you.  I learned that the hard way.

Comment: So it all comes down to whether leaving it spinning is better/worse than power cycling. @sawdust referred to this as a debate - I take it there's no consensus?

Comment: I'd say power cycling twice a week is much better than leaving it spinning all week. But I don't know about twice an hour.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Typical wear for a mechanical hard drive comes from spinning the platters, and moving the head.  Short of stopping those there isn't much that can be done that will offer a significant reduction in wear.  The amount of drive access needed to verify the drive is mounted is negligible compared to leaving it unmounted.